# Draw image with transparency

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a few pngs which I overlay on each other to form a single image in beginGraphicsContextWithOptions....  However, I want to draw some of these images with transparency. How can I do this please?

Comment: Do you want to apply an alpha to the images when you combine them, or do you just mean to use the transparency that the images already have?

Comment: The images have no transparency. I want to selectively apply transparency to some of the images when I draw them.

Comment: What I would do is set up a destination buffer, expand each image into its own buffer, loop through the image data one pixel at a time, write the pixel to the destination buffer (blending it according to your desired alpha and what's already there), then create a new context, and use the destination buffer to draw a new CGImage, make a new UIImage with that, and that should do it.  I'm super tired right now, but I'll be in the office on Monday and I've got some code that could help you.  That should at least give you an idea of where you might start though.  Good luck in the meantime!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would overlay images with transparancy:

```
NSString* file1 = "your images file path";

NSRect largerect = NSRectMake(10,10,300,300);

NSString* file2 = "your images file path";

NSString* file3 = "your images file path";

NSString* file4 = "your images file path";

NSImage* img1 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file1];

NSImage* img2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file1];

NSImage* img3 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file1];

NSImage* img4 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file1];

//the fraction parameter is just how transparent you want it so 1.0 is opaque and 0.0      you will not see the image

[image1 drawInRect: largeRect
      fromRect: NSZeroRect
     operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
      fraction: 0.8];

[image2 drawInRect: largeRect
      fromRect: NSZeroRect
     operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
      fraction: 0.6];

[image1 drawInRect: smallRect1
      fromRect: NSZeroRect
     operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
      fraction: 0.40];

[image2 drawInRect: smallRect2
      fromRect: NSZeroRect
     operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
      fraction: 0.40];
```

Comment: Sorry, this is an iOS question, but your answer did make me go check the docs again and UIImage now has a blend mode method with an alpha component